# Spawn image views with time increment

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How can I programmatically spawn an unlimited number of `UIImageViews` on to the screen in a random location on a time increment. The random location would be:`CGPoint(arc4random() % (481), arc4random() % (321),20,20)` I just don't understand how to constantly create new ones with one image variable and a for loop. Or an `NSTimer` that on every increment adds a new image to the screen.

I know there are some tutorials out there for this, but the only ones I could find used automatic reference counting. It should be simple to create, and a link is fine.

---

Other questions:

UI is for user-interface, but since i'm not using a storyboard or xib, would there be a better type of `imageView` to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this, in your view controller class (substituting your own image file name of course):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.5 target:self selector:@selector(addViews:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)addViews: (NSTimer *) aTimer {
    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"New_PICT0011.jpg"]];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(arc4random() % (481), arc4random() % (321), 20, 20);
    [iv setFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:iv];
}
```

You would have to put some kind of counter in there, and when it got to the total number of views you wanted, call [aTimer invalidate];

Comment: yes it works, plus 1 to you, i might have a few more questions

Comment: instead of retrieving the timer count, can i retrieve how many iv are on the screen

Comment: Putting a counter in the addViews method would be counting the number of view on screen, since you get one view for every time it's called. There is no timer count.